# Convert a quadratic curve points to polynomial representation?

Tags: language-agnostic, bezier, curve, polynomial-math, quadratic

I have the X,Y of 2 *end* points and 1 *bezier* point, of a *Quadratic Bezier* curve.

Using this data, how can I derive the *polynomial representation* of the curve?

[image]
<sub>(source: [euclidraw.com](http://www.euclidraw.com/Eng_fls/EUC_htmls/Bezier_fls/quad.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

B(t) = (1-t) * (1-t) * B0 + 2 * (1-t) * t * B1 + t * t * B2

Comment: Oh. If that's what the OP was looking for, then you're exactly correct. (at least Wikipedia corroborates it ;) I thought he was trying to get a polynomial equation without the parameter t in it.

Answer (score 1):

Oog. That would be tricky. [Beziers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) are parametrized curves, namely:

```
x = f(t)
y = g(t)
```

where t=0 yields one endpoint and t=1 yields the other.

You could technically figure out how to eliminate "t" and get an equation in x and y, but it would not be a polynomial like y = a + bx + cx<sup>2</sup> ...; it would be an equation h(x,y) = 0 where h is probably somewhat ugly.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Polynomial_form) has a section about this. Perhaps this helps.